# Iframes, child pages and functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I have an aspx page with some controls. One of which is an `iframe`, whose source changes (depending on the selection in a `listbox`). So, if a user selects an item in the `listbox` (ie: `Claims.aspx`), the `iframe`s source changes to `Claims.aspx`.

I have a button on my 'child' pages (ie: `Claims.aspx`). I'd really like to have that button execute either:

1. Javascript from the 'parent' page
2. A VB function in the code-behind of the 'parent' page

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'java'? Maybe you should switch it to Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent page and your content page are both on the same domain (which I'm presuming they are) you can simply do:

```
parent.myFunction();
```

from your content page to access `myFunction()` in your parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Town's answer, you can also use `top` as in

`top.myFunction();`

to call the parent's `myFunction` function from the Iframe.